# Twice-ran behavior of a try-catch-raise exception clause in Python

Tags: python, pandas, exception

In the following minimal example, I wrap the `pandas.DataFrame.apply` method with my own method, `safe_apply`. This method differs from a normal `apply` in two ways:

1. Instead of returning values in an `NDFrame`, it appends them to a list, `results`.
2. If an exception is caught, `results` is printed before the error is raised and execution terminated.

Here is the code:

```
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame, Series
import pandas as pd

def safe_apply(df, func, **kwargs):
    results = []

    def new_func(srs):
        try:
            results.append(func(srs))
        except Exception as e:
            print(results)
            raise

    df.apply(new_func, **kwargs)
    return results

DataFrame.safe_apply = safe_apply

def f(srs):
    if (pd.notnull(srs['lat'])) & (pd.notnull(srs['long'])):
        return srs['lat'] + srs['long']
    else:
        raise ValueError


ex = pd.DataFrame({'lat': [1, 2, None], 'long': [1, 2, None]}, index=['A', 'B', 'C'])
ex.safe_apply(f, axis='columns')
```

When I execute this, I except the result of applying the function `f` to the first two rows of `ex` and then failing on the third: a `print` out of `[2.0, 4.0]`, followed by a `ValueError`

Instead I get a `ValueError` and **two** lines of output:

```
[2.0, 4.0]
[2.0, 4.0, 2.0, 4.0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-382c07ef0919> in <module>()
     26         raise ValueError
     27 
---> 28 ex.safe_apply(f, axis='columns')

<ipython-input-1-382c07ef0919> in safe_apply(df, func, **kwargs)
     12             raise
     13 
---> 14     df.apply(new_func, **kwargs)
     15 
     16     return results

C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)
   4059                     if reduce is None:
   4060                         reduce = True
-> 4061                     return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)
   4062             else:
   4063                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)

C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures, reduce)
   4155             try:
   4156                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
-> 4157                     results[i] = func(v)
   4158                     keys.append(v.name)
   4159             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-1-382c07ef0919> in new_func(srs)
      7     def new_func(srs):
      8         try:
----> 9             results.append(func(srs))
     10         except Exception as e:
     11             print(results)

<ipython-input-1-382c07ef0919> in f(srs)
     24         return srs['lat'] + srs['long']
     25     else:
---> 26         raise ValueError
     27 
     28 ex.safe_apply(f, axis='columns')

ValueError: occurred at index C
```

Meaning that the code reached the exception clause, printed out `results`, and then instead of throwing an error and stopping, *ran the function again* (?) somehow.

Why does this occur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the notes section on the [docstring](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), specifically

> In the current implementation apply calls func twice on the first column/row to decide whether it can take a fast or slow code path. This can lead to unexpected behavior if func has side-effects, as they will take effect twice for the first column/row.